# How to prevent Tkinter multithread from running the function twice?

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a Tkinter tool which may help me keep copying the text and search it on google without pasting.

In the beginning, when I pressed "Enable Copy", the Tkinter freezed.
So, I used **threading** module to separate the copy function. Otherwise, I cannot press "Stop" while the copy function is working.

However, now when I pressed "Enable Copy", I can only search the text from my clipboard for the first time. After that, I copied the text once but searched it twice no matter what.

I guess the reason might be the "threading" module, but the Tkinter would freeze without it...
That's where I got stucked.

If anyone has better idea, please kindly advise.

My Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard
import webbrowser
import threading
class myGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread_running = bool
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.title("Copy Tool")
        self.win.geometry('300x50')
        tk.Button(self.win, text="Enable Copy", command=self.start_thread).pack()
        tk.Button(self.win, text="Stop", command=self.close_thread).pack()
    def copy_(self):
        while self.thread_running:
            
            if keyboard.read_key()== "ctrl" and keyboard.read_key()== "c":
                text_fromcopy=self.win.clipboard_get()
                print(text_fromcopy)
                if "&" in text_fromcopy:
                    text_fromcopy = text_fromcopy.replace("&", "%26")
                url = "https://www.google.com/search?q={}".format(text_fromcopy)
                webbrowser.open(url,new=0)
    def close_thread(self):
        self.thread_running = False
    def start_thread(self):
        self.thread_running = True
        threading.Thread(target=self.copy_).start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = myGUI()
    app.win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you using that approach when you can use `keyboard.add_hotkey("control+c", <function>)` instead?

Comment: Is that the reanson for it running twice?

Comment: Change in line 27 threading.Thread(None, myGUI.copy_).start()

Comment: @toyotaSupra That isn't going to work because the function `copy_` requires 1 parameter `self`, which you can pass in using `self.copy_`. `myGUI.copy_()` is going to say that 1 parameter is needed.

Comment: @TheLizzard. Thank. I was made as mistaken. You're right. Sorry about that.